# Django 3 ModelForm NameError? I'm sure there's a glaring error but I just cannot see it?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Hoping for a bit of help, I've been trying to deal with this error for about 3hrs and I'm going around in circles.

Django 3 project. It's a simple app for leaving a review for a product and I keep getting a NameError and I just can't figure out what it is?

## models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm, Textarea, CharField
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from products.models import Product

SCORE_CHOICES = [
    ('1', 'One'),
    ('2', 'Two'),
    ('3', 'Three'),
    ('4', 'Four'),
    ('5', 'Five'),
]   
class Review(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
    review_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    review_text = models.TextField(default='')
    score = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=SCORE_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Review for user {self.user.username}'

class ReviewForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = ['user', 'product', 'date', 'review_title', 'review_text', 'score']
        widgets = {
            'review_text': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 100, 'rows': 20}),
        }
```

## forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from products.models import Product
from review.models import Review, ReviewForm

class ReviewForm(forms.Form):
    product = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Product.objects.all())
    review_title = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    review_text = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.Textarea)
    score = forms.CharField(
        max_length=3,
        widget=forms.Select(choices=SCORE_CHOICES),
    )
    date = forms.DateField(auto_now=True, editable=False, null=False, blank=False)
    user = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import *

@login_required
def writeReview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReviewForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks')
    else:
        form = ReviewForm()
    context = {'form': form, 'menu_class': 'menu-login'}
    return render(request, 'review/displayWriteReview.html', context)
```

I keep getting the following error and just cannot see it. Calling it a day but if anyone can point me in the right direction where I've gone wrong I'd be so very appreciative.

## Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/peggy/candles/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/peggy/candles/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/peggy/candles/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/peggy/candles/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/peggy/candles/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/check.py", line 64, in handle
    fail_level=getattr(checks, options['fail_level']),
  File "/Users/peggy/candles/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 395, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Users/peggy/candles/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/peggy/candles/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Users/peggy/candles/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "/Users/peggy/candles/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "/Users/peggy/candles/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/peggy/candles/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Users/peggy/candles/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/peggy/candles/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 581, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/peggy/candles/candles/urls.py", line 29, in <module>
    path('review/', include('review.urls')),
  File "/Users/peggy/candles/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/peggy/candles/review/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from review import views
  File "/Users/peggy/candles/review/views.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .forms import *
  File "/Users/peggy/candles/review/forms.py", line 6, in <module>
    class ReviewForm(forms.Form):
  File "/Users/peggy/candles/review/forms.py", line 12, in ReviewForm
    widget=forms.Select(choices=SCORE_CHOICES),
NameError: name 'SCORE_CHOICES' is not defined
```

Sincerest of thanks in advance for any help.

Wayne :)

Comment: You simply need to import SCORE_CHOICES into the forms.py file.

Answer (score 0):

You never imported this from the models, so `from review.models import …, SCORE_CHOICES`:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from products.models import Product
from review.models import Review, ReviewForm, SCORE_CHOICES

class ReviewForm(forms.Form):
    product = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Product.objects.all())
    review_title = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    review_text = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.Textarea)
    score = forms.CharField(
        max_length=3,
        widget=forms.Select(choices=SCORE_CHOICES),
    )
    date = forms.DateField(auto_now=True, editable=False, null=False, blank=False)
    user = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: Hi Willem, thank you so much. I had one of those 'Homer Simpson' moment over coffee this morning. I think i need to take some more coffee breaks throughout the day. Really appreciated and thank you for time. Wayne :)